# Github Pages doesn't show my background images

Tags: html, github

I was doing a portfolio project on my own and had a problem and don't know how to fix it.
When I go to the github's live page it doesn't show me the background.
Fun fact is that on VS Code it works so idk.

Here's the project: https://github.com/bautitobal/mi-portfolio
Live page: https://bautitobal.github.io/mi-portfolio/

Tried with img/fondo.jpg and even with 'https://bautitobal.github.io/mi-portfolio/mi-portfolio/img/fondo.jpg'

Comment: Use your network inspector tools, some of your URLs are pointing to the wrong directory

Comment: For example, fondo.jpg is accessible through https://bautitobal.github.io/mi-portfolio/img/fondo.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope it can help U, it work for me

```
.inicio{
background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(30,35,38,.8), rgba(30,35,38,1)),
url('../img/fondo.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```css
.inicio{
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(30,35,38,.8), rgba(30,35,38,1)), url('../img/fondo.jpg');
 }
```

this seems file path issue you need to get to the image folder from your css folder